# Configuring server port and response header and query parameter

Tags: java, jetty

I am using: org.mortbay.jetty.Server.

I am initiallizing the server like this:

```
private static Server server = null;
server =  (Server)applicationContext.getBean("HQSimJettyServer");
```

How can i configure the server port after the getBean method? i can do it in the server constructor, but since i am using the getBean, i cant define the port in the consructor.

Secondly, how can i define the server response to include header and query parameters?

Right now i am using:

```
return Response.status(response_code).build();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you usin Spring to get the bean?

Comment: Yes i am using org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(String name)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using spring then define the bean in the application.xml to call the constructor with arguments if your choice.

Spring way:

```
private static Server server = null;
server =  (Server)applicationContext.getBean("HQSimJettyServer");
```

XML snippet:

```
<bean id="HQSimJettyServer" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server" >
    <constructor-arg value="10000"/>
</bean>
```

Alternative way (no Spring dependency):

```
 Server s = new Server();
 SocketConnector socketConnector = new SocketConnector();
 socketConnector.setPort(10000);
 s.addConnector(socketConnector);
```

Or simply:

```
Server s = new Server(10000);
```

You can of course combine the above if you wish to get the Server instance from Spring and then add Connectors in your code.

Comment: How do i set the argument in the xml file? for exmple if i have a String named port_num in my program how do i set the attribute "port" which means the port the server is listening in the xml file?